# AS3: How to find source of embed fonts?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts, swfobject, swfloader

I'm investigating huge legacy project, where many SWF assets are dynamically loaded. I guess designers used embedded fonts in Flash IDE. Now I'm making localization and my issue is that embedded `Futura` font doesn't have non-english symbols. I've added correct ttf font:

```
[Embed(source="../../../../../assets/fonts/FuturaBT-ExtraBlackCondensed.ttf", fontFamily="Futura Extra Black Condensed BT", mimeType="application/x-font", embedAsCFF="false")]
private const FONT_FUTURA_EXTRA_BLACK_CONDENSED:Class;
```

I've removed all places in main code with `Font.registerFont()`
It works, but when I check `Font.enumerateFonts(false)` to show all embedded fonts it shows some mess:

```
[trace] Fonts : embedded 21 / all 192
[trace]     Arial / regular / embeddedCFF
[trace]     Arial / bold / embedded
[trace]     Arial / regular / embedded
[trace]     Arial / regular / embedded
[trace]     Arial Black / regular / embeddedCFF
[trace]     Arial Bold / regular / embeddedCFF
[trace]     Arial Bold / bold / embedded
[trace]     DS-Digital / bold / embedded
[trace]     Futura Extra Black Condensed BT / regular / embedded
[trace]     Futura Extra Black Condensed BT / regular / embedded
[trace]     ITCOfficinaSans LT Book / bold / embedded
[trace]     ITCOfficinaSerif LT Book / bold / embedded
[trace]     Myriad Pro / regular / embedded
[trace]     Myriad Pro Bold / bold / embedded
[trace]     Myriad Pro Bold Condensed / bold / embedded
[trace]     Myriad Pro Light / bold / embedded
[trace]     Myriad Pro Semibold / bold / embedded
[trace]     Rockwell Extra Bold / regular / embedded
[trace]     Times New Roman / regular / embeddedCFF
[trace]     VAG Rounded BT / regular / embedded
[trace]     VAG Rounded LT CYR Bold / bold / embedded
```

I'm worried that invalid `Futura Extra Black Condensed BT` is still there. 
So I have 2 questions:

1. How to find source of those embed fonts?
2. Is there way to
   remove or hide font after it was embedded somehow?

Comment: They could be embedded via Flash IDE. Any text field has "Embed" button which opens a certain interface with the list of all the fonts marked for embedding in the FLA source you are editing. When publishing, these fonts are embedded into the resulting SWF.

Comment: Ok, but is there way to protect my main SWF from outdated fonts while loading other SWF?

Comment: **Loader.load** has second argument that allows to load external SWF into separate addressing context. I think that will do it for you.

Comment: One more thing. You actually can track where these fonts come from. First, **Loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getQualifiedDefinitionNames()** https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#getQualifiedDefinitionNames() Second, use JPEXS tool to look into SWFs and find out which fonts are embedded there.